# Breeze/Angular: date input directive not working/strange behaviour

Tags: angularjs, date, breeze

I'm trying to get this directive (https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime) to work in my project. It works alright in the following plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DawLbi?p=preview

But when I plug in the same code (below) into my larger scale project, it doesn't work and I have no idea why and where to search.

```
<input type="text" datetime="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="vm.firstDate" class="form-control" data-z-validate />
```

What happens: The input displays the formatted date correctly, but when I click on the year (or some other component) and try to change it using the number keys (enter a new year), it clears out the whole field (upon entering the first digit)! Using the up/down arrow keys works.

The problem happens only when I use the data-model on a breeze-entity. If I just put a simple js Date object on my controller and link to that one, it works.

I also tried extending my breeze entity like so:

```
function registerRechnungRec(metadataStore) {
            metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(g14EntityNames.rechnung, RechnungRec, postCtorInitializer);

            function RechnungRec() {
                this.datumExt = moment().toDate();  // doesn't work
            }

            function postCtorInitializer(rechnung) {
                // this works, but not tracked by breeze then
                rechnung.datumExtDate = moment(rechnung.datum).toDate();
            }

            // also no luck with that one:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982624/angular-and-breeze-edit-date-object
            //addDateWrapperPropertyExt(RechnungRec, 'datum', 'datumExtDate');        
        }
```

A normal input with type date works just fine for entering/selecting the date. But I need to do some momentjs formatting afterwards to save the date correctly to the database then before I call entityManager.save(). Also, I don't really need the whole date picker component, a simple date input is all we need.

- So how do I find out what's going wrong where?
- Or is there another suggested date input directive/component, or an easier way to just have a text input field that allows me to input a date (no time) or a null date?